# Should I use MongoDb module or morphia module or Casbah in play framework for MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, playframework, casbah

I am working on a play framework project with scala in which I want to have Scala domain classes (or even Java domain classes) using MongoDb as data store.

I want maximum performance while serving hundreds of thousands  if not millions of requests per day.

Since both scala language and Play framework is adding new features by the month, what is the best answer in terms of latest production version of the modules mentioned in the question
and play framework 1.2.2, scala 0.9.1+  and scala language 2.8+?

Comment: What did you end up doing for your project? I had the same question myself

Comment: I found the MongoDb module to be unusable in Scala because of Scala's lack of support for Java static methods. Scala doesn't use static methods, but instead uses singleton instances which are similar to Java's static.  Also, the Mongo module didn't look like it was being maintained.

I haven't had a chance to try Morphia in a Scala project, nor Casbah yet.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone stumbling upon this question and using playframwork 2.1.x or above I highly recommend taking a look at [reactivemongo site](http://reactivemongo.org/) and [github project](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo).
It's a mongodb scala driver that allows asynchronous db operations.
Great performance and mature enough for use in production.

At the time of writing this the current version is 0.9 and is being used by us in production without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Morphia](http://www.playframework.org/modules/morphia) module, a MongoDB integration for Play! 1.2.x

Answer (score 0):

For scala I would suggest you have a look at https://github.com/novus/salat
I've written a play plugin for salat which you can find here https://github.com/leon/play-salat

Good luck!